Tag synonym: visual-system for vision
I have proposed a synonym for vision from  visual-system as I think systems-level physiologists might be more familiar with the latter terminology.
Also, the synonym for schizophrenia is still sitting in the queue, as it was put in as a suggestion from a user rather than done using the mod tools.

I just approved them.

@JeromyAnglim Thanks!
